# Tensorflow rank not good?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, rank

i'm trying to minimize a simple loss defined on four variable tensors of the same size (n*m)

```
def matloss(pm,pv,qm,qv):
    pv=tf.clip_by_value(pv,1e-3,100)
    qv=tf.clip_by_value(qv,1e-3,100)

    dpv=tf.reduce_prod(pv,reduction_indices=1)
    dqv=tf.reduce_prod(qv,reduction_indices=1)
    iqv = 1./qv
    diff = qm - pm
    loss=0.5*(tf.log(dqv / dpv) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(iqv,pv),reduction_indices=1)+ tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(tf.mul(diff,iqv),diff),reduction_indices=1) - tf.to_float(tf.shape(pm)[1]))
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

The problem is when i'm running optimization, i have the following error:

ValueError: Shape () must have rank 1

the function matloss return the good loss value, but when i'm trying to minimize it the rank problem occurs

Am i missing something here? 
Thank you

```
m1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m],mean=1.0, stddev=0.35))
v1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m],mean=1.0, stddev=0.35))
m2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m],mean=1.0, stddev=0.35))
v2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m],mean=1.0, stddev=0.35))
loss=matloss(m1,v1,m2,v2)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
sess = tf.Session()

with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5000):
        sess.run(opt)
```

Can someone copy paste my code and try it to tell me if i'm the only one who get this error?

Comment: What are `n` and `m`? In which line the error occurs?

Comment: n and m are radom integers, for example 20 and 10.
The error occurs when writing the optimizer
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? You can also inspect the runtime shape of the tensor being fed to the optimizer by adding some code along the lines of `print(sess.run(tf.shape(loss)))` after your `sess.run(init)` call. What shape does it print?

Comment: The shape is exactly the same than a classical loss such as an l2 loss for instance:
loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(m1-m2)))

The problem comes from the first term of the defined loss tf.log(dqv / dpv) because when i remove it it works just fine, but i can't find why